# After building wxWidgets with VS2012, which files can I delete in the lib folder?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, wxwidgets

I've built wxWidgets with VisualStudio Express 2012 (nmake) and I don't know which files I can delete in the lib folder.  The following file types are in the lib folder: .exp .manifest .ilk .pdb .lib .dll

I know I need the .lib and .dll, but what are the rest for?  In another build, I also have these file types: .obj .tlog .log

What of these types are files that I can safely delete?

Comment: Just leave 'em be.  They do no harm.  Move on and tackle a real problem

Comment: The files themselves make no problems. I want to clean up my lib-folders from garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it helps to know what the files are for

- exp: definition which function to export by the linker [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se8y7dcs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- obj: output of the compilation, which normaly gets used by the linker to generate the binary [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w63ck4sd.aspx)
- ilk: used by vc to speed up the generation (on multiple times) [3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1716cz97.aspx)
- pdb: contains info for use by the debugger and linker [4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- tlog: used by vc to speedup compilation time [5](http://dickyjim.wordpress.com/tag/tlog-files/)

Comment: Thank you, that's the first useful answer. Ok, some types speed up compilation, but the build-process is finished. I don't want to compile these libs again. I will only use these libs for my projects. Will I need these types any more, when I just link them to my projects? I have a dev-folder with all the libs I need for my projects and I will delete every single file which I don't really need.

Comment: I would at least keep the pdb's to get help while debugging into one of those librarys

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely keep the `.pdb` files to be able to debug. The rest of them (not counting `.lib` and `.dll`, obviously) could be deleted but IMHO it's not worth it. If you're after space saving, you should delete the entire `build/msw/vc_mswu[d][dll]` (or `build/msw/vc11_mswu[d][dll]` if you use per-version build directories) directory as this is what really takes a lot of place.

Comment: You are right. It does not worth. The ratio between my .dll .lib and .pdb and the rest is to low.